# How to validate input SSN validation field

Tags: javascript, validation, model-view-controller, view, field

Field should be formatted for SSN.

- 9 numerical digits only + 2 dashes (XXX-XX-XXXX)

  ```
    <div class="col-md-6" data-number="0" id="amdCorrSSNcont">
        <label for="correctSSN">Correct SSN</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="XXX-XX-XXXX"  class="form-control" id="correctSSN">
    </div>
  ```

How can I format the field ?

Answer (score 0):

Using RegEx is probably the best way. Make sure field max-length is correct, and use the pattern match for ###-##-####

**^([0-9]{3}[-]{1}[0-9]{2}[-]{1}[0-9]{4})**

A useful tool for creating Regex Patterns is https://regexr.com/

Comment: `{1}` is never useful in a regex. There is no need to put the hyphen in a character class, either.

Comment: Hey! I am new to this RegEx, could you please demonstrate how to use regex, or assign regex value to input field.
Thank you..

Comment: Sure @Ben   . The input tag has a attribute called "pattern", that you can use to require the input match the specified text pattern. You can use regexr.com to design the regex, and then paste it into the pattern="" attribute. If the user types in a pattern that doesn't match, it will prevent them from submitting          <input type="text" placeholder="###-##-####" class="form-control" maxlength="11" pattern="^([0-9]{3}[-]{1}[0-9]{2}[-]{1}[0-9]{4})" id="correctSSN">

Comment: @Ben No problem, glad to help. Could you please mark this as the accepted answer if it solved your problem?  --Thanks David